# Java: Cut a Number after a Specific Word in a Sentence

Tags: java, numbers, substring, cpu-word, sentence

I have a sentence like this:

```
String str = "This is a sample 123 string 456. And continue 123...";
// OR
String str = "This is another sample 123 and other words. And 123";
// I want => int result = 123;
```

How can I cut only **number** `123` after the **word** `sample`?

Comment: You can use a  regex `"sample.*(\\d+)"` with a Matcher.

Comment: Go through regex..https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: @PeterLawrey your solution will return `3` instead you should to remove the `*` `"sample.(\\d+)"`

Comment: @YCF_L the * is required in case there is not exactly one character between the word and number, if you know it will be a space that could be used.

Comment: mmm, but it return 3 in both cases @PeterLawrey ! how did you explain that?

Comment: @YCF_L which api are you referring to? Matcher returns either boolean or a String.

Comment: Why (-1)...? I don't understand...

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you check https://regex101.com/r/nkRopi/1 did i make a mistake ?

Comment: @YCF_L yes but so did I. When used in a String \\ becomes \ but .* should be .*? So it is not eager.

Comment: what did you mean @PeterLawrey i don't get you, how the regex should look like?

Comment: @YCF_L "\\bsample\\b.*? (\\d+)" makes a regex of `\bsample\b.*?(\d+)`

Comment: mmm i see now it work https://regex101.com/r/mQPV5a/1

Comment: thank you for the free lesson @PeterLawrey i appreciate it :)

Comment: @YCF_L thank you for picking up my error.

Comment: you qre welcome @PeterLawrey

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, so if your look your number exist between `sample` and `space` so you can use this :

```
public static final String REGEX_START = Pattern.quote("sample ");
public static final String REGEX_END = Pattern.quote(" ");
public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX_START + "(.*?)" + REGEX_END);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "This is a sample 123 string 456. And continue 123...";
    List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>();

    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(input);

    // Check for matches
    while (matcher.find()) {
        keywords.add(matcher.group(1)); 
    }

    keywords.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Or you can use the solution of @Peter Lawrey just remove the `*`

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("sample.(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(input);

// Check for matches
while (matcher.find()) {
    keywords.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```